# Appending a Component Programatically

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to build a very simplified version of an infinite scroll.

I currently have everything working fine apart from the posts coming from the posts component.

In my main component for the blog page

I have the following

```
<Index id="posts-container">
    <Posts posts={postsChunked[0]} />
</Index>
```

I am using `useEffect()` in the upper part of the component to split my post array, this is taken from graphQL and formated nicely into an array to pass to my Posts component).

Within that `useEffect()` function I have the right `postsChunked` array loading to console.

What I need to know is how can I push this array, `postsChunked[1]` for example, into the Index container from within `useEffect()` (if that's the right way).

Essentially I want the following depending on the number of pages but I need page 1 and 2 loading afterwards but unsure on how to fire that in from `useEffect()`

```
<Index id="posts-container">
    <Posts posts={postsChunked[0]} />
    <Posts posts={postsChunked[1]} />
    <Posts posts={postsChunked[2]} />
</Index>
```

FYI This is my first Gatsby build :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a state where you store your array of post chunks.

```
const [postChunks, setPostChunks] = React.useState([]);
```

When you fetch more data, append them to this state.

```
const loadMoreDataSomehow = async () => {
  const newPostsChunk = await fetch('/somewhere'); // this will be an array of post; a postChunk
  setState(prev => [...prev, newPostsChunk]);
}
```

And finally, render them by calling `.map()` on the array:

```
return (
  <Index id="posts-container">
    {postChunks.map((postChunk, index) => (
      <Posts posts={postChunk} key={index} />
    ))}
  </Index>
);
```

Ideally, you shouldn't use `index` as the `key`, though. You can probably use the concatenated `ids` of all the posts in the chunk.

Comment: This works brilliantly. Tweaked it around a bit to suit but state was the way to go.

Thanks for your help

PS. Tried to edit that last block as it was missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the map block.

Comment: Whoops, fixed that missing parenthesis. I was writing the code directly on SO without testing it on an IDE, tbh, haha. Glad that it helped.

Comment: @Jackyef Any idea how you would extend this further. Say his number of chunks started causing performance because of the number of objects on the screen. I'm thinking along the lines of a list-view where it shifts the first chunk.

Comment: I believe you should look into [`react-window`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) for rendering a huge list of item and keeping them performant. https://react-window.now.sh/#/examples/list/fixed-size